# Wordpress form value save to database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress popups plugin for opening form in lightbox.

Url: https://wordpress.org/plugins/popups/

Now i have created new popup and in editor i wrote following code

```
<form>First name:
<input name="firstname" type="text" />Last name:
<input name="lastname" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

My question is how can i save user details in database table.what are the steps to acheive this

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$website = "http://example.com";
$userdata = array(
    'first_name'  =>  $_REQUEST['first_name'],
    'last_name'  =>  $_REQUEST['last_name']
    );

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

//On success
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo "User created : ". $user_id;
}

?>
```

Comment: i need to define something in form action right,and where i will put above code

Comment: `<form action="" method="post">` change the form tag

and put the answer in functions.php

`if($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'){ // answer here}`

Comment: dont  forget to accept the answer ;) if it works for you

Comment: its not working i have chaged wp-includes/functions.php in last i have added following function mysql_to_rfc3339( $date_string ) {
 $formatted = mysql2date( 'c', $date_string, false );

 // Strip timezone information
 return preg_replace( '/(?:Z|[+-]\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)$/', '', $formatted );
}

if($_POST['submit'] == 'submit'){ 
 $userdata = array(
    'first_name'  =>  $_REQUEST['first_name'],
    'last_name'  =>  $_REQUEST['last_name']
    );

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;



if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    echo "User created : ". $user_id;
}

 }

Comment: Hey bhagwaan ... not in wp-includes in the active theme folder under wp-content/themes/YOURFOLDER put in that functions.php